# Why do react elements outside of Route re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Open the [sidebar example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar) in official docs of react router. You can see that `ul` is rendered without `Route` since it is supposed to be there on screen irrespective of the url. Open React DevTools, check `Highlight updates` checkbox and click on any of the menu items in the side bar. You will notice that elements under `ul` re-render on every click. In my opinion, it is not sane behavior, react elements under `ul` should not re-render with route change given they are not rendered by react routers `Route` component. Is there a way I can stop them re-rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Router component depends on context for the change and whenver a context value is updated, it triggers a re-render of the children to do a match and render the appropriate route. Now since the `ul element` is directly written as a `child of Router`, it also gets re-rendered. Although react performs a virtual-dom comparison and the DOM won't be re-rendered, you can avoid it by using a `PureComponent` and writing ul elements within that `Component`

```
const SidebarExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <div
        style={{
          padding: "10px",
          width: "40%",
          background: "#f0f0f0"
        }}
      >
        <Route component={Elements}/>
        {routes.map((route, index) => (
          // You can render a <Route> in as many places
          // as you want in your app. It will render along
          // with any other <Route>s that also match the URL.
          // So, a sidebar or breadcrumbs or anything else
          // that requires you to render multiple things
          // in multiple places at the same URL is nothing
          // more than multiple <Route>s.
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={route.sidebar}
          />
        ))}
      </div>

      <div style={{ flex: 1, padding: "10px" }}>
        {routes.map((route, index) => (
          // Render more <Route>s with the same paths as
          // above, but different components this time.
          <Route
            key={index}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={route.main}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </Router>

)

class Elements extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
          <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", padding: 0 }}>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/bubblegum">Bubblegum</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/shoelaces">Shoelaces</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        )
    }
}
```